# PHP MySQL merge rows with same column value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table looks like this:

```
year | url                | view
-------------------------------
2016 | /document/item.pdf | 21
2015 | /document/item.pdf | 35
2014 | /document/item.pdf | 41
```

and I want build another table looks like this :

```
 url                | 2014 | 2015 | 2016
---------------------------------------
 /document/item.pdf | 41   | 35   | 21
```

I don't really now how I have to write my mysql query to do that.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please don't make us guess your requirements. And please provide some insights to what you have tried so far.
As it stands, your question looks suspiciously like a "do my homework" question (which typically get closed rather quickly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can try this:

```
 SELECT  url,
            MAX(IF(`year` = 2014 , view, NULL)) '2014',
            MAX(IF(`year` = 2015, view, NULL)) '2015',
            MAX(IF(`year` = 2016, view, NULL)) '2016'
    FROM    pub
    GROUP   BY url
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Query all data from your first table to PHP array, the array would be like:

   ```
   $data = [[2016, "/document/item.pdf", 21],
       [2015, "/document/item.pdf", 35],
       [2014, "/document/item.pdf", 41]];
   ```
2. Traverse `$data`, make another associated array `$result`, whose key is url, value is an array of data with year and view:

   ```
   $result = array();
   foreach ($data as $value) {
       $result[$value['url']][$value['year']] = $value['view'];
   }
   ```
3. Traverse the new array, and write data back to MySQL

Comment: I was focused on a mysql query but it works fine with an array. Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 0):

you must make two table -> first to save files , second to save visits
like this

Files Table

```
url_id | url
------------------------
1      |/document/item.pdf 
2      |/document/item.pdf
```

Visits Table (url_id) is forign key from files table

```
url_id | time
---------------
1       | 987907872     
2       | 987907872
2       | 987978272
2       | 987907872
2       | 987907872
1       | 987907872
1       | 987907872
1       | 987907872
```

========================

then you can check time by year in visits table to view number of visits of each URL

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you

```
SELECT 
    url, 
    sum( if( year= '2014', view, 0 ) ) AS 2014,  
    sum( if( year= '2015', view, 0 ) ) AS 2015, 
    sum( if( year= '2016', view, 0 ) ) AS 2016 
FROM 
    pub
GROUP BY 
    url;
```